# Rails 4 precompiled assets upload to Amazon s3 and cloudfront

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have used asset-sync and fog gem for assets upload to aws s3.I can uploaded precompiled assets files to aws-s3 while deploying but it taking lot of time.The deploy is not complete then it was stopped on bundle exec rake assets:precompile command.

Gem file:

```
gem "fog", "~>1.20", require: "fog/aws/storage"
gem 'asset_sync'
```

Asset sync configuration file:

```
 AssetSync.configure do |config|
    config.fog_provider = 'AWS'
    config.aws_access_key_id = "Your aws access key"
    config.aws_secret_access_key = "Your aws secret access key"
    config.fog_directory = ENV['FOGDIRECTORY']
    config.fog_region = 'us-west-2'
 end
```

Staging.rb file:

```
 config.assets.enabled = true
 config.assets.digest = true
 config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://djrcjofcge7nb.cloudfront.net"
 config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://djrcjofcge7nb.cloudfront.net"
 config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following configurations in your `staging.rb` file

```
config.assets.compile = true
config.eager_load = true
```